# How do I define sequences in FactoryGirlRails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec2, factory-bot

Previously in Factory girl, we could define sequences like so:

```
# /spec/factories.rb

FactoryGirl.define do

  # this is the sequence in question:
  sequence(:random_token) { Digest::MD5.hexdigest(rand.to_s) }

  factory :story do
    sequence(:title) { |n| "My Cool Story##{n}"  }
    # Call the sequence here:
    token { Factory.next(:random_token) }
    description { "#{title} description"}
  end

end
```

Now, when I try that approach - I get a deprecation warning telling me:

```
WARNING: FactoryGirl::Sequence#next is deprecated.
Use #run instead.
```

When I replace #next with #run, I get a no-method error.
I can't find the new syntax in any of the docs... Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think you should use `Factory.create(...)` instead, e.g.

```
token { Factory.create(:random_token) }
```