# FactoryGirl WARNING Sequence#next is deprecated

Tags: ruby-on-rails, factory-bot, shoulda

I am using FactoryGirl with Shoulda to test my application.

Actually my code works fine, but I am getting warning that #next method was deprecated.
I can't find solution how to avoid this. I can't see anywhere the proposed 
run method..  Some opinions?

```
Factory.define :user do |user|
  user.first_name       'John'
  user.last_name        'Sheppard'
  user.after_create { |_t| _t.contact.update_attribute :email, Factory.next(:email) }
end

Factory.sequence :email do |n|
    "john#{n}.sheppard@topmonks.com"
end
```

WARNING: FactoryGirl::Sequence#next is deprecated.
Use #run instead.

Comment: Maybe @bodacious question [How do I define sequences in FactoryGirlRails?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5497801/how-do-i-define-sequences-in-factorygirlrails) will help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should just be able to call Factory(:email) here  - you will get the next in the sequence automatically

Answer (score 1):

As of version **4.2.0** `FactoryGirl.generate(:email)` works